# Solve the equation $2^{3x+4} = 4 \sqrt 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Help??????

Before hand I had to write sqrt $2$ as a power of $2$ then express $4$ $\sqrt 2$ as a power of $2$. How to solve the above equation I am not too sure!?

Comment: can you state what you already tried?

Answer (score 6):

I assume that it is supposed to be $$2^{3x+4}=4\sqrt 2.$$ After writing $4=2^2$ and $\sqrt 2=2^\frac12,$ we find that $$4\sqrt 2=2^{2+\frac12}=2^{\frac52},$$ so $$2^{3x+4}=2^{\frac52}.$$ What can we do now?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**:

$4\sqrt2$$= 2^{\frac52}=2^{3x+4}$.

Equate the powers and **VOILA**.

Comment: VOILA! nice thing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $2^a=2^b\implies a=b, a\in\mathbb{R},b\in\mathbb{R}.$